# Transactional annotation not working with Autowired constructor

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, autowired, spring-transactions

I have a following situation:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final MyRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(MyRepository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public List<Data> getData(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveData(Data data){
        repository.save(data);
    }
}
```

When I call the `saveData` method, the `@Transactional` annotation is not applied and the method throws TransactionRequiredException.

How to enable the `@Transactional` annotation to work?

Answer (score 0):

Using this method, the Spring for some reason incorrectly initializes the bean and does not apply the annotation.

One fix I have found is to use field autowiring instead of constructor autowiring. Like this:

I have a following situation:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    public List<Data> getData(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveData(Data data){
        repository.save(data);
    }
}
```

This way the bean is correctly proxied and the AOP framework can apply the necessary annotations.